# Is there a version history for SharePoint 2010 list's custom "new item" form

Tags: forms, list, sharepoint, versioning, restore

I accidentally modified and saved a SharePoint list custom "new form", which was previously created by a person I don't know. Now I want to restore a previous version of that form, but I cannot find a version history of this list form.

We all know, that in SharePoint Designer every SharePoint site page can be restored to a previous version very easily (for example by right clicking and choosing version history)

But is there any version history for a list form?

***The list form I'm speaking about is not the default NewForm.aspx, but was created and set as default new form.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Site Pages you refer to are stored in Document Libraries with enabled version control. The List Forms are stored in special subfolders of lists and libraries that are not subject to version control. Unfortunately, you'll have to restore the site from a database backup (which is hopefully still available) to a dummy web application, then open the form in SharePoint Designer and copy the source code from there.